# Unable to select Checkbox inside TreeView

Tags: python, qt, treeview, pyqt, pyqt4

I tried creating a treeview with checkboxes but I'm unable to select the checkboxes.

on the flag method I had mentioned it as ItemisuserCheckable but still could not get it working...

am I missing something here to enable the selection of checkboxes.

A snippet of the code is:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class StbTreeView(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, args, parent=None):
        super(StbTreeView, self).__init__(parent)

        self.args = args
        print self.args

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.args)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return QString("Select STB's")

    def flags(self, index):
        row = index.row()
        if row:
            return  Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            return self.args[row]

        if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:

            row = index.row()
            return QVariant(Qt.Unchecked)

    def setData(self, index, value, role):

        if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
            if value == Qt.Checked:
                row = index.row()
                selected_stb = self.args[row]
                print 'selected_stb is %s' % selected_stb
                print 'Value is %s' % value
                self.emit(SIGNAL("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"),index, index)
                return True
            #return QVariant(Qt.Checked)

def main():
    myapp = QApplication(sys.argv)

    data = ['STB1', 'STB2', 'STB3', 'STB4', 'STB5', 'STB6', 'STB7', 'STB8']

    model = StbTreeView(data)
    tree_view = QTreeView()
    tree_view.show()
    tree_view.setModel(model)

    myapp.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to hold somewhere current item state (checked\unchecked) and change it once setdata() method is called. Your items are always unchecked because you're always returning `QVariant(Qt.Unchecked)` for them in the data() method.

I've changed a bit your code, see it would work for you:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class TestItem():
    def __init__(self, name, checked):
        self.checked = checked
        self.name = name

class StbTreeView(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, args, parent=None):
        super(StbTreeView, self).__init__(parent)

        self.args = []
        for item_name in args:
            self.args.append(TestItem(item_name, False))

        for item in self.args:
            print item.name

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.args)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return QString("Select STB's")

    def flags(self, index):
        return  Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            print self.args[row].name
            return self.args[row].name

        if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
            row = index.row()
            print self.args[row].checked
            if self.args[row].checked == False:
                return QVariant(Qt.Unchecked)
            else:
                return QVariant(Qt.Checked)

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
            row = index.row()
            self.args[row].checked = not self.args[row].checked             
        return True

def main():
    myapp = QApplication(sys.argv)

    data = ['STB1', 'STB2', 'STB3', 'STB4', 'STB5', 'STB6', 'STB7', 'STB8']

    model = StbTreeView(data)
    tree_view = QTreeView()
    tree_view.show()
    tree_view.setModel(model)

    myapp.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Thnaks It worked perfectly for me... But I wanted to pull this tree view on a combo box using the code as mentioned below.. But i was not able to make it working either.. Just wondering if Im doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it really worked for me. My Original requirement was to call this view/model on a combo box. I tried calling this but it did not work ... I'm able to see the view inside the combo box but unable to select any of the check boxes. I tried quite a few possibility but did not succeed..

Did a slight modification on your code to call from combo box.

the modified code is:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class TestItem():
    def __init__(self, name, checked):
        self.checked = checked
        self.name = name

class StbTreeView(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, args, parent = None):
        super(StbTreeView, self).__init__(parent)

        self.args = []
        for item_name in args:
            self.args.append(TestItem(item_name, False))

        for item in self.args:
            print item.name

    #print 'Value of self.args is %s' % self.args

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.args)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return QString("Select STB's")

    def flags(self, index):
        return  Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            print self.args[row].name
            return self.args[row].name

        if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
            row = index.row()
            print self.args[row].checked
            if self.args[row].checked == False:
                return QVariant(Qt.Unchecked)
            else:
                return QVariant(Qt.Checked)

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
            row = index.row()
            self.args[row].checked = not self.args[row].checked             
        return True

class Template(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Template, self).__init__(parent)

        self.data = ['STB1', 'STB2', 'STB3', 'STB4', 'STB5', 'STB6', 'STB7', 'STB8']
        self.MainUI()

    def MainUI(self):
        self.model = StbTreeView(self.data)
        self.setModel(self.model)


def main():
    myapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    temp = Template()
    temp.show()
    myapp.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code from combo box:

```
stb_listview = QComboBox()
view = Template()
stb_listview.setView(view)
stb_listview.setModel(view.model)
```